# LineBreak in console object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Line break in javascipt string console

```
console.log("Foo" + "\n" + "Bar");
```

Line break in javascript object console

```
console.log({ value : "Foo\nBar" });
```

Is it possible to add linebreaks in javascript objects.

Comment: just use _back ticks_ for multiline strings.

Comment: I can do that but I want to know if I can add line breaks in object

Comment: Depending on your environment, you may want to switch to `console.table({ value : "Foo\nBar" });`.

Comment: The output of `console` logging is [implementation-dependant](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#logger).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no: when you print an object to the console log, strings will be written as javascript objects (similar but not identical to what you'd get if you explicitly converted them into JSON, like `console.log(JSON.stringify(object))`).

If you want for some reason to print your strings with line breaks, you'd have to implement the object-to-string conversion yourself; perhaps with something like this:

```
function customString(object) {
    let string = '{\n';
    Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
        string += '  "' + key + '": "' + object[key] + '"\n';
    });
    string += '}';
    return string;
}

console.log(customString({ value: "Foo\nBar" }));
```

(It sounds like you have an idea in mind of exactly how you want this output to look, so adjust the function above until it works as expected.)

Answer (score 2):

You can make JSON pretty with automatic line breaks using:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify({ test: { key: { inner: 'val' } }}, null , 2))
```

Where 2 is the number of spaces/indent for each level.

Answer (score 0):

I think its originally creating a line break, but due to the object, it's not showing directly. Try to assign it in variable and access that in the console.

Code:

```
var v = {val:"test\ntest"};
console.log(v.val);
```

Output:

```
 test
test
```

Comment: clever! Thank you. Works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6:

```
console.log(`hello
world`)
```

will produce:

```
hello
world
```